# Insert, update and delete animations with ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, listview, animation, foreach, swiftui

I managed to have a nice insert and delete animation for items displayed in a `ForEach` (done via `.transition(...)` on `Row`). But sadly this animation is also triggered when I just update the name of `Item` in the observed array. Of course this is because it actually is a new view (you can see that, since `onAppear()` of `Row` is called).

As we all know the recommended way of managing lists with cool animations would be `List` but I think that many people would like to avoid the standard UI or the limitations that come along with this element.

A working SwiftUI **example snippet is attached** (Build with Xcode 11.4)

So, the question:

> **Is there a smart way to suppress the animation (or have another one) for just updated items that would keep the same position? Is there a cool possibility to "reuse" the row and just update it?**

Or is the answer "Let's wait for the next WWDC and let's see if Apple will fix it..."? ;-)

Cheers,
Orlando

---

**Edit**

bonky fronks answer is actually a good approach when you can distinguish between edit/add/delete (e.g. by manual user actions). As soon as the `items` array gets updated in background (for example by synced updates coming from Core Data in your view model) you don't know if this is an update or not. But maybe in this case the answer would be to manually implement the insert/update/delete cases in the view model.

---

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items: [Item] = [
        Item(name: "Tim"),
        Item(name: "Steve"),
        Item(name: "Bill")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Row(name: item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: AddButton, trailing: RenameButton)
        }
    }

    private var AddButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.items.insert(Item(name: "Jeff"), at: 0)
        }) {
            Text("Add")
        }
    }

    private var RenameButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.items[0].name = "Craigh"
        }) {
            Text("Rename first")
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {

    @State var name: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .animation(.spring())
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {

    let id: UUID
    var name: String

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Luckily this is actually really easy to do. Simply remove `.animation(.spring())` on your Row, and wrap any changes in `withAnimation(.spring()) { ... }`.

So the add button will look like this:

```
private var AddButton: some View {
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            self.items.insert(Item(name: "Jeff"), at: 0)
        }
    }) {
        Text("Add")
    }
}
```

and your Row will look like this:

```
struct Row: View {

    @State var name: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, this solves the problem because in this example I can distinguish between add and edit. But unfortunately this is not an option when the items array is updated in background (e.g. by incoming core data updates in the view model). Since this was not clear in my question I will update it ...

Comment: Since your answer is correct to my non-updated question I will accept it. On the other side I hope that some alternatives will follow up ;) Thanks again.

Comment: As far as I know there's no 'clean' way to do this. You could try adding an abstraction layer in which you'll add a `didSet` to the data that gets updated in the background. Then you set the data that's used in your UI with `withAnimation`.

Answer (score -1):

The animation must be added on the `VStack` with the modifier `animation(.spring, value: items)` where `items` is the value with respect to which you want to animate the view. `items` must be an `Equatable` value.
This way, you can also animate values that you receive from your view model.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Row(name: item.name)
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: items) // <<< here 
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: AddButton, trailing: RenameButton)
    }
}
```