# SwiftUI: delete animation in List?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI View that shows a list of items. The view is pretty large so I won't paste the whole thing here. However, the List uses a ForEach:

```
ForEach(model.items, id: \.id) { item in
    myCell(item: item)
}
```

Everything works fine. What I am trying to do is **have a simple slide animation when an item is deleted in the model**.

I looked at this answer on stack:

[Insert, update and delete animations with ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486483/insert-update-and-delete-animations-with-foreach-in-swiftui)

However, my setup is different and I am not sure how to try to apply that to my case. In that link the items are stored as a @State property in the view.

My setup is the view uses as @StateObject:

```
@StateObject var model = MyViewModel()
```

The model has this:

```
@Published var items = [MyStruct]()
```

The List's cells allow the swipe action, the user taps on delete, and the view tells the model to delete that specific item.

The model then has async logic that kicks in and eventually (pretty much immediately) removes the related item from its `items`. When that happens the List updates, the cell goes away and all works.

I would like to add a **cell delete animation**. How can I do that given my setup?

EDIT

Trying to add more code to help with context.

The deletion is triggered from an alert like so:

```
return Alert(
    title: Text(title),
    message: Text("You cannot undo this action"),
    primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
    withAnimation {
        model.deleteItem(id)
    }
    },
    secondaryButton: .cancel()
)
```

I added that `withAnimation` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Likely you just have to add `withAnimation` in your delete logic. But, it's impossible to know for sure without seeing a [mre].

Comment: How would I add a `withAnimation` if the deletion happens in the model class?

Comment: You wrap the deletion within `withAnimation { }`

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

so I found what was making things not work even `withAnimation`.

My model has a call:

```
model.deleteItem(id)
```

Internally, as part of the work needed to delete that item, `deleteItem(id)` uses a `Task.init { ... }` task. I was then jumping back on main to then update items `@Published var items = [MyStruct]()` in the model.

The async nature of it broke the `withAnimation`.

I pulled out the removal of the item from `items` and left it `sync` within the `withAnimation` call and now the default delete animation works.

So, as long as the removal is synchronous within the `withAnimation` call, the animation kicks in.